# Organizing code in tkinter - buttons/labels

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote some code looking like that:

```
define f(i):
    """ f is a function that takes an integer i and gives me back another integer """ 
    return ...

window = Tk()

#start
i = 54 #that is just an integer I can choose

.
.
.

I created buttons and Labels whose parameters depend on i
.
.
.
#end
B_final = Button(...)  

window.mainloop()
```

I would like `B_final` to be a button that does what I did with `i` for the lines that are between `#start` and `#end` but for an another integer `f(i)`. I thought of writing a function depending on `i` with the block of code I had between `#start` and `#end` and then calling this function when clicking on `B_final` but the labels and buttons did not work as I intended. How should I proceed? Should I define my labels and buttons regardless of `i`and then change their parameters in a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to create the labels and buttons before assigning their values, this can be done later with an `B_final.config(text=i)`.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

i = 54

def function():
    """function alters global variable i and updates B_final button""" 
    # Changing i
    global i
    i += 1 # This can be whatever that needs to change to i
    # Updating button
    B_final.config(text=i)  
    B_final.update()
    
# Creating window
window = tk.Tk()

# Creating button and packing it
B_final = tk.Button(window, text=i, command=function)
B_final.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

However, it depends on what your `i` is, if it's a response from a user interaction then putting the `B_final.config(text=i)` and `B_final.update()` within the called function might the best in your use case.

Comment: Thank you, I took time to reread my code and organized it better. The truth was that I had an issue with images, but it is solved now.

Answer (score 1):

You can create widgets (like buttons, labels, etc) and then later configure them, with the `config()` call.

So, I could say:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(text='press me', background='red')
```

Or, I could make the last line into two:

```
button = tk.Button()
button.config(text='press me', background='red')
```

So, the moral of the story is that you can always go back and reconfigure widgets in a function call or any other way you want, well after they've been created.

So, if you want a function that configures your widgets, you can make a function that takes an argument that is used to generate some combination of things to do to some widgets.